# Find if Date is weekend or weekday in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a Dataframe, df, with 3 columns: Year, Month and Date. I want to use this information to determine if this date falls on a weekend or weekday and which day of the week it is.

I am trying to use the below code to determine if its weekend or weekday but it is not working

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def is_weekend(d = datetime.today()):
  return d.weekday() > 4
```

```
df['weekend'] = df.apply(lambda x: is_weekend(date(x['Year'], x['Month'], x['Day'])), axis=1)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Apart from this, how do I find out if this date falls on which day of the week.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can first form a `dates` series from your `Year`, `Month` and `Day` columns:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime({"year": df.Year, "month": df.Month, "day": df.Day})
```

then you can check the `dayofweek` (note the `dt` accessor before it):

```
df["Day of Week"] = dates.dt.dayofweek
```

and form the `is_weekend` column with your logic:

```
df["Is Weekend"] = dates.dt.dayofweek > 4
```

where we don't need `apply` anymore since we have a unified `dates` series and it supports this kind of all-at-once comparison.

Answer (score 7):

How about we do it in a readable self-explanatory way?

```py
dates = pd.to_datetime({"year": df.Year, "month": df.Month, "day": df.Day})
df["Is Weekend"] = dates.dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'])
```

Comment: Hi, for the above code. How could we modify this so instead of populating Is Weekend column with true or false, it populates it with weekend or weekday. This way its easier to plot.

Comment: Sorry, I quick google reveals this could be acheived with ...df['is_weekend'] = np.where(df['ride_dow'].isin(['Saturday','Sunday']), 'weekend', 'weekday')

Comment: @chucknor use `.loc` instead. `df.loc[df['day_of_week'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'], 'weekday_weekend'] = 'weekend'`

Comment: That doesn't work. Looks like there is a closing parenthesis missing. I ran ...df_rides['is_weekend'] = df_rides.loc[df_rides['ride_dow'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']), 'weekday_weekend'] = 'weekend'. So this populates Saturday and Sunday days with weekend but how to I populate weekdays with weekday. Above leaves them as NaN.

Comment: `mask = df['day_of_week'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'])`, `df.loc[mask, 'col'] = 'val_true'`, `df.loc[~mask, 'col'] = 'val_false'`. This is the pandas way. Although `np.where` seems more elegant. Not sure how it compares performance-wise. I suspect `.loc` should be faster and more memory efficient. In case you need it.